# Is there a way to preview a file in Google Cloud Storage? A way to see the first few lines without downloading the entire file?

Tags: google-cloud-storage

I just want to see the column headers for a CSV file so I can create a table before importing it into Cloud SQL. Preferably using the web-based Storage Browser at https://console.cloud.google.com/storage/browser

Answer (score 18, accepted):

I think I found a way. Open up the Google Cloud Shell (one of the icons in the upper right) and use the "gsutil cat" with the -r range option or pipe it through head.